# iOS: Navigation Controller title not centered

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a navigation controller with a custom back button on the left.  I do this programmatically so this is not an auto-layout issue.  My problem is that the navigation controller title is not centered, it is going off the right side of the screen.  I remember seeing a fix for this awhile back dealing with setting some type of fixed space as the right bar button item, but I cannot seem to find anything similar to this now.

Could someone tell me how to set the navigation controller title to centered and if the title is too big for its space, set nav bar title to fix its font size to fit the width of title space.  This all needs to be done programmatically, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is not centered because the view is too big. Are you trying to set just a plain text to the title?

Comment: What do you mean by the view is too big, I am not setting a custom view for the title.  I am setting title by self.title = @"This is my title";

Comment: please look at the debug view heirarchy in xcode ,so that you can get idea of what causes the title to appear on right side

Comment: The title is appearing on the right side because the text is too long.  It starts where it normally would on the left side but font size stays the same and it runs off the right side of the view.  @Nikunj might have the best approach here since it would give me some freedom to customize the title however I would like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks so much for the answers, they were useful in helping my find a solution.  My solution was to use the titleView property of the navigation controller.  It sets the title without having to go through the trouble of making a custom UIView and the setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property solved my problem of the font size being too big.  I've added a little extra formatting to make it look nice, but I won't post it since it doesn't have to do with my question.  Here is the code I am using:

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-60, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
titleLabel.text = @"This is my big, long title";
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[titleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

Answer (score 8):

In navigation controller, by default, the view controller A that pushes current view controller B. The title of A will show up in backBarButton in view controller B.

The navigation controller title not centered is also because the previous view controller title is too long.

To counter that, use this in `viewWillAppear` of view controller A:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem= UIBarButtonItem(title: "", 
    style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem!.title = ""`
```

Comment: This worked great.  Here is the equivalent code in Objective-C that worked for me.     self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

Answer (score 2):

You have to add custom view in the navigation

```
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 150, 44)];

    UILabel *titleLabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 165,370, 25)];
    titleLabel.text=@"Home";
    titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [view addSubview:titleLabel];    
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:view];
```

Comment: if it work for you so please accept my answer @MSU_Bulldog

Answer (score 2):

Try out this, it would help you and it is tested.

**Objective C version**

```
UIButton * button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourSelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"<" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-3, -15, 3, 15);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIBarButtonItem *leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem;
```

**Swift version**

```
button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,50, 50))
        button?.addTarget(self, action: "backButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button?.setTitle("<", forState: .Normal)
        button?.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: kFontHelveticaNeueRegular, size: 30)
        button?.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-3, -15, 3, 15)
        button?.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)

        var leftItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button!)
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem
```

Comment: why did you post an answer for button ? The question is asked for navbar title. Please modify your answer according to it

Comment: I updated this answer because of the method which is used for making the navigation bar is not good. that is why update it to make it more useful for user.

Answer (score 2):

Add following method in your Utilities class

```
+ (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];
    [label setText:title];
    [label sizeToFit];

    viewController.navigationItem.titleView = label;
}
```

Use across view controllers as follows

```
[Utilities setTitle:@"Title for View Controller" forViewController:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add both leftbarbutton and Rightbarbutton . Usually back button exist . If you add an empty right bar button , title will get centered.